# Max and min of $f(x,y)=e^{|y+\arctan x|^{\alpha}}$ on a domain $D$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=e^{|y+\arctan x|^{\alpha}}$ on the domain $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<x^3\le y\le \sqrt{x}\}$.

Domain $D$ is a compact, $f\in C(D)$, so for Weierstrass theorem absolute max and min exist on $D$.
If $\alpha=0$, $f(x,y)=e$ so $\max f=\min f=e$.
But if $\alpha \ne0$ how can I calculate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. First of all $D$ is not compact because $(0,0)\not \in D$, but it is in its closure. Note that for $(x,y)\in D\subset [0,1]^2$,
$$0+\arctan(0)=0<y+\arctan(x)\leq 1+\arctan(1)=1+\pi/4.$$
Moreover, the function
$(0,+\infty)\ni t\to e^{|t|^{\alpha}}$
 is continuous, it is strictly increasing for $\alpha>0$, and it is strictly decreasing for $\alpha<0$.

Comment: so for $\alpha>0$ Inf f is (0,0) and Max f is (1,1)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Comment: but if $\alpha <0$?

Comment: Well, think about it!

Comment: for $\alpha <0$ exchanging roles?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: if I use levels curves i found $y=-arctan x+(\ln c)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$.For $\alpha>0$ the curves go up and in (0,0) I have an Inf and in (1,1) a Max. For $\alpha<0$ Min is in (1,1) and Sup is in (0,0)?

Comment: Yes! That's correct.